OAuth2 with ASWebAuthenticationSession on watchOS
Does anyone have an example of OAuth2 working successfully in a watchOS app using the ASWebAuthenticationSession class?
Example with iOS app worked. But the same URL does not work on the watch. Instead of the login page, you are redirected to an error page.
